# Can the old gods in World of Warcraft die?

Tags: warcraft

In the war between the Titan and Old-gods, the Titans couldn't kill the Old gods they just neutralized them and sealed them. And even in their weaker form they are still powerful.

**Examples** include:

- C'thun created the quiraj and turn Neltharion mad.
- N'Zoth created the emerald nightmare .
- Y'Shaarj is supposedly slay but his heart is still beating .
- Yogg-Saron created the faceless ones.

In the game you can make a raid to kill C'thun and Yogg-saron, but are really they dead in  the canon plot (like Arthas or Deathwing)?

Comment: Since World of Warcraft, pretty much any iconic Warcraft figure can die in a raid and respawn the next attempt. Even the most powerful creatures can now succumb to some random guy tagging along. You should define the scope of your question, because I'm pretty sure there are quite a few who still want to consider anything happening in WoW as "non-canon" for example (at least I do...).

Comment: in Wrath of the Lich King when you kill  the lich king the lore explains that Tirion Fordring and the champions of the argent tournament kill arthas and is canon also when you kill nightwing but there is none of the old gods

Comment: Blizzard likes to pick-and-choose what's canon from the game, but has never outright answered the overall question. I like to think that the events of the world happen in canon, but only the first time. In other words, from the player's perspective, they and 39 other people went into AQ and killed C'Thun. Then they beat up Illidan. Next they killed Arthas. Etc. etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old god in Pandaria was killed by the Titans and its heart was locked up and buried underground. That is what Garrosh Hellscream finds and corrupts him for the final raid. After Garrosh is defeated and the heart is destroyed for good the old god is completely and utterly dead. Thus, the Titans could kill the old gods, but Azeroth is to corrupted by them and the planet would be destroyed, which is why the Titans just sealed them.